# .NET Crystal Reports Export to Text with Page Breaks/Headings

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a number of Crystal Reports that I am exporting to text in vb.net.  It exports just fine, but all as one page - there are no page breaks or page headings.  I can change this by changing the `FormatOptions.LinesPerPage = 0` bit to something else, but the reports being exported are all different.  What would work for one would not necessarily work for another.  I'd rather not have to code something separate for each report.

Is there a way to pass the Crystal Reports page break to the export text?  Or to another format (say, .pdf?)

```
Dim crReportDocument As New ReportDocument
Dim ExportOpts As New ExportOptions
Dim DestinationOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
Dim FormatOptions As New TextFormatOptions

crReportDocument.Load(strFileName)
ExportOpts = crReportDocument.ExportOptions

DestinationOptions.DiskFileName = strNewFileName
FormatOptions.CharactersPerInch = 16
FormatOptions.LinesPerPage = 0
With ExportOpts
    .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
    .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Text
    .DestinationOptions = DestinationOptions
    .ExportFormatOptions = FormatOptions
End With

crReportDocument.Export(ExportOpts)
crReportDocument.Close()
crReportDocument.Dispose()
```

Comment: Text files don't have page breaks. You probably want to export to pdf, and let the page breaks be controlled by the report sections.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Thanks!